# .removeAttr() not removing data-toggle from tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Situation**

I am working on a program where I have multiple tabs.
However, a user cannot go to another tab unless they save and an ID is returned. Therefore on my `document.ready` I have the following code that is supposed to strip the tab attribute from the tab.

```
    function DisableTabs() {
        alert('1');
        if ($("#applicationID").val() == null || $("#applicationID").val().toString().length <= 0 || parseInt($("#applicationID").val()) <= 0) {
            $("#dvAttach").removeAttr('data-toggle', 'tab');
            $("#dvAttach").removeAttr('onclick')
            $("#dvAttach").attr('onclick', 'ValidateTabs();');
            alert('2');
        }
        alert('3');
    }
```

I am calling this function in my document.ready and the alerts all show and this is the code for the tabs.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#dvInfo" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Application Information</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#dvAttach" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" onclick="GetFiles()">Attachments</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Problem**

As I mentioned in my title, I can click on the tab, even if applicationID has no value. When I load the page and I inspect the tab, I still see it has it's `data-toggle` attribute.

Grateful if any help could be provided.

Comment: Please only include relevant tags in your question.

Comment: Don't see any elements with `id="dvAttach"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, in your javascript code at line 4 and 5 you are trying to select element with Id dvAttach (using '#dvAttach') but you dont have element with id as dvAttach. Add id="dvAttach" to your element where you want to remove the attribute!

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#dvInfo" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Application Information</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#dvAttach" id="dvAttach" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" onclick="GetFiles()">Attachments</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Stupid mistake, I mistook the href for ID even if I look at it like 100 times. I'm embarrased.